# Actionscript - shortcut reference to long class names

Tags: actionscript, import, classname

Is there a way to do something akin to `import <BLAH> as` in actionscript? I've got some classes that I don't want to type the full class name out for every time I use them. That's why I'm trying to find an import as, or `var C = ImportedClassThatIDontWantToTypeEveryTime`. I've tried a few different ways, such as:

```
package com.mysite.blah {
    // doesn't work
    import com.mysite.ImportedClassThatIDontWantToTypeEveryTime as C;

    // also doesn't work
    import com.mysite.ImportedClassThatIDontWantToTypeEveryTime;
    var C:Class = ImportedClassThatIDontWantToTypeEveryTime;

    // ????

    public class SomeOtherClass {

        public function blah():void {

            C.doSomething();

        }

    }

}
```

I know there is a way to do this - I've done it before years ago. However, I can't remember how to do it. Help?

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? I ask this because I haven't had to type out a class-path in full in years. The auto-complete features of both [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) and [FlashBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) will allow you to type the first couple of letters of the class you want in place, select it from a list, and it will automatically add the appropriate `import` statement to the top of your class.